# How can I connect (stack) two Cisco SG350 together?

Tags: cisco, switch, stacking, cisco-sg300

I am building a storage network, physically separated from the data network. I have two Cisco SG350-28P-K9 V02 switches:

- One on the basement. Has two NAS, two ESX servers. (in use)
- One on the 4th floor. Has one NAS, two ESX servers. (to be added)
- Two runs between basement and 4th floor: one fiber, one ethernet.

I am trying to have the two switches work as one, so that all NAS / Servers can see each other across the two floors. Should I stack them? if so, I don't see any settings to do this on the advanced GUI, not the console.

Can you shine some light on how to archive this? Thank you!

Info Switch 1:

```
System Description: SG350-28P 28-Port Gigabit PoE Managed Switch    
Host Name:  vmswitch1   Edit
System Object ID:   1.3.6.1.4.1.9.6.1.95.28.5   
System Uptime:  216 day(s), 18 hr(s), 34 min(s) and 21 sec(s)   
Current Time:   14:57:17;2019-Oct-15    
Base MAC Address:   00:7e:95:52:c6:78   
Jumbo Frames:   Enabled 
Firmware Version (Active Image):    2.4.5.71
Firmware MD5 Checksum (Active Image):   2dff89efdb2a0ec2f9a2c414ff7d401c
Firmware Version (Non-active):  2.3.5.63
Firmware MD5 Checksum (Non-active): 5881484e04bcdcc17c32872445e3ab8d
```

Here is info on switch 2:

```
System Description: SG350-28P 28-Port Gigabit PoE Managed Switch    
System Location:    IT Closet
Host Name:  vmswitch2
System Object ID:   1.3.6.1.4.1.9.6.1.95.28.5   
System Uptime:  3 day(s), 21 hr(s), 33 min(s) and 13 sec(s) 
Current Time:   14:56:03;2019-Oct-15    
Base MAC Address:   2c:73:a0:fd:dd:6b   
Jumbo Frames:   Enabled 
Firmware Version (Active Image):    2.4.0.94
Firmware MD5 Checksum (Active Image):   6f5be217100f34929986f2e93dd2d5e9
Firmware Version (Non-active):  2.4.0.94
Firmware MD5 Checksum (Non-active): 6f5be217100f34929986f2e93dd2d5e9
```

Comment: "_Two runs between basement and 4th floor: one fiber, one ethernet_" What are you running on the fiber? Is the ethernet also fiber? I do not thionk those switches are stackable, but you can have a single layer-2 domain, or you can use a router between them for separate layer-3 domains.

Comment: Thank you. One run is point to point fiber. The other is cat6. At the moment there is no traffic in neither of the runs. Layer-2 domain would be a VLAN? if yes, how should I achieve this?

Comment: Simply connecting the two switches will make a single layer-2 broadcast domain. If you do that, you want the layer-3 network addressing to be in the same network.

Comment: Thank you. I did connect the two switches using one run at one point. All devices are in the 10.10.74.0/24 network. I was able to ping from one server on the basement to the NAS on the 4th floor, however ESX would not "see" the iSCSI volumes on the NAS. Now, connecting the cable directly to the NAS (bypassing the second switch, would show the iSCSI volumes) So, i thought I was doing something wrong in the switch side.

Comment: @acanessa If you've got VLANs configure for iSCSI (which generally is a good idea) you'll need a VLAN trunk between the switches.

Comment: @RonMaupin thank you! you gave me a clue, and i double checked jumbo frames on the switch. I had tried what you suggested but still, i could not access iscsi datastores, even being able to ping between esx and synology.

I was sure that i had jumbo frames enabled on the switch, however that was not the case! Enabling jumbo frames solved the issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I thought i had jumbo frames enabled on the second switch, but that was not the case. That's why i was able to ping the storage from the ESX, but unable to connect to the iSCSI volumes. i did not need to stack the switches. Just having a layer-2 domain (as @RonMaupin suggested on the comments section) with jumbo frames enabled worked.

Answer (score 0):

The SG350 does not have stacking capability, only PIDs with an X on the end are stackable. EX: SG350X